# OPA List of objects - Finding two values in multiples objects within list

Tags: opa, rego

Due to limitations, I am using if/else blocks within OPA. I am writing control rules where it will fail all conditions and pass the remaining. I have a list of extensions (objects) where each object represents one extension available on your device in the input data. I am trying to analyze to see whether 2 different extensions are available. The idea is if `jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_].name == SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)` then in the same object,  within the same object `jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_].values` should NOT be empty to pass. The sample input below should reach the bottom of my Rego rule and pass but it keeps returning fail.

Here is the sample input:

input.json

```
{
    "jamf": {
        "isManaged": true,
        "jamf_details": {
            "operatingSystem": {
                "extensionAttributes": [
                    {
                        "values": [1,2,3,4
                        ],
                        "dataType": "STRING",
                        "name": "SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)",
                        "options": [],
                        "description": "Reports",
                        "inputType": "SCRIPT",
                        "multiValue": false,
                        "enabled": true,
                        "definitionId": "84"
                    },
                    {
                        "dataType": "INTEGER",
                        "values": [],
                        "name": "OS-Uptime Days",
                        "options": [],
                        "description": "12345",
                        "inputType": "SCRIPT",
                        "multiValue": false,
                        "enabled": true,
                        "definitionId": "10"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "asset": {
        "name": "Mac",
        "id": "190",
        "type": "workstation",
        "category": "infrastructure"
    },
    "user": {
        "roles": "Principal",
        "email": "test@test.co"
    }
}
```

Here is my rego rule:

```
ccm_wks_jmf_2 = exception {
    input.exception
    exception := {eval_doc_xcloud("pass", data.control.ccm_wks_jmf_2, input)}
}

else := disallow {
    itema := input.jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_]
    itema.name == "SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)"
    a := itema.values
    count(a) < 1
    itemb := input.jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_]
    itemb.name == "SW esensor-SYSX (com.systemextension)"
    b := itemb.values
    count(b) < 1
    input.jamf.isManaged == true
    input.user.email
    disallow := {eval_doc_xcloud("fail", data.control.ccm_wks_jmf_2, input)}
}

else := disallow {
    itema := input.jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_]
    itema.name == "SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)"
    a := itema.values
    count(a) < 1
    itemb := input.jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_]
    itemb.name != "SW esensor-SYSX (com.systemextension)"
    input.jamf.isManaged == true
    input.user.email
    disallow := {eval_doc_xcloud("fail", data.control.ccm_wks_jmf_2, input)}
}

else := disallow {
    itemb := input.jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_]
    itemb.name == "SW esensor-SYSX (com.systemextension)"
    b := itemb.values
    count(b) < 1
    itema := input.jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_]
    itema.name != "SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)"
    input.jamf.isManaged == true
    input.user.email
    disallow := {eval_doc_xcloud("fail", data.control.ccm_wks_jmf_2, input)}
}

else := disallow {
    itema := input.jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_]
    itema.name != "SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)"
    itemb := input.jamf.jamf_details.operatingSystem.extensionAttributes[_]
    itemb.name != "SW esensor-SYSX (com.systemextension)"
    input.jamf.isManaged == true
    input.user.email
    disallow := {eval_doc_xcloud("fail", data.control.ccm_wks_jmf_2, input)}
}

else := allow {
    allow := {eval_doc_xcloud("pass", data.control.ccm_wks_jmf_2, input)}
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

In the sample input, I am expecting it to pass since values array is not null and extension name `SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)` exists. You can see that I'm also looking for the possibility of another extension. Same idea where either or extension exist, the values should not be empty to pass.

Passing input

```
                "extensionAttributes": [
                    {
                        "values": [1,2,3,4
                        ],
                        "dataType": "STRING",
                        "name": "SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)",
```

Failing input

```
                "extensionAttributes": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                        ],
                        "dataType": "STRING",
                        "name": "SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)",
```

or another failing input (since values is empty for each extension that we're looking for)

```
                "extensionAttributes": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                        ],
                        "dataType": "STRING",
                        "name": "SW-agent-SYSX (co.systemextension)"
                    },
                    {
                        "values": [
                        ],
                        "dataType": "STRING",
                        "name": "SW esensor-SYSX (com.systemextension)"
                    }
```